# Check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method

Tags: dependency-injection, permissions, dependency-management, resolve, abp

> The requested service 'Volo.Abp.PermissionManagement.PermissionManagementProvider' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

[image]

```cs
namespace SecurityDomainModule
{
    [DependsOn(
        typeof(AbpDddDomainModule),
        typeof(SecurityDomainSharedModule),
        typeof(AbpUsersDomainModule),
        typeof(AbpUsersDomainSharedModule),
        typeof(AbpPermissionManagementApplicationContractsModule),
        typeof(AbpPermissionManagementDomainModule),
        typeof(AbpPermissionManagementDomainSharedModule),
        typeof(AbpPermissionManagementDomainIdentityModule),
        typeof(AbpPermissionManagementApplicationContractsModule),
        typeof(AbpPermissionManagementEntityFrameworkCoreModule)
    )]
    public class SecurityDomainModule : AbpModule
    {
        public SecurityDomainModule()
        {
        }

        public override void PreConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
        {
            // ...
            AutoAddPermissionManagementProviders(context.Services);
            // ...
        }

        private static void AutoAddPermissionManagementProviders(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<PermissionManagementOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ManagementProviders.Add<BusinessSegmentPermissionManagementProvider>();
                options.ManagementProviders.Add<CustomPartnerPermissionmanagementProvider>();
                options.ManagementProviders.Add<CustomTeamPermissionmanagementProvider>();
                options.ManagementProviders.Add<PermissionManagementProvider>();
                //options.ManagementProviders.Add<RolePermissionManagementProvider>();
                // Role and User providers are already added by default. So not adding them here.
            });
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

To reproduce the bug, I am trying below test case:

```cs
public async Task<List<PermissionWithGrantedProviders>> GetAllForRoleAsync(string roleName)
{
    try
    {
        Check.NotNullOrEmpty(roleName, nameof(roleName));

        var result = await RolePermissionManagerExtensions.GetAllForRoleAsync(_permissionManager, roleName);
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //TODO log exception return null;
    }
}
```

Calling `RolePermissionManagerExtensions` method, however it gives an error saying `PermissionManagementProvider` is not registered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PermissionManagementProvider` is an `abstract` class, so don't add it to `options.ManagementProviders`.

```cs
private static void AutoAddPermissionManagementProviders(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<PermissionManagementOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ManagementProviders.Add<BusinessSegmentPermissionManagementProvider>();
        options.ManagementProviders.Add<CustomPartnerPermissionmanagementProvider>();
        options.ManagementProviders.Add<CustomTeamPermissionmanagementProvider>();
        options.ManagementProviders.Add<PermissionManagementProvider>(); // Remove this
        // ...
    });
}
```

Comment: after removing the above line,  am getting different errors as below:                                       An exception was thrown while activating Volo.Abp.PermissionManagement.Identity.RolePermissionManagementProvider -> Volo.Abp.Identity.UserRoleFinder.

Comment: InnerException says:                                                                                          None of the constructors found with 'Volo.Abp.Autofac.AbpAutofacConstructorFinder' on type 'Volo.Abp.Identity.UserRoleFinder' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Volo.Abp.Identity.IIdentityUserRepository identityUserRepository' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Volo.Abp.Identity.IIdentityUserRepository)'.

Comment: Specify `DependsOn` your EF Core module or `AbpIdentityEntityFrameworkCoreModule`.

Comment: After adding AbpIdentityEntityFrameworkCoreModule the issue got fix.  Thank you so much @aaron